# Should I ask a question about graph theory algorithms here or on theoretical cs?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am taking an undergraduate course targeted at both CS and math students, called "efficient algorithms". It explains graph algorithms, like solutions for the Travelling salesman etc. It is not about implementing them, but about proving why they work. Now there are some things I don't understand about a maximum flow algorithm, and wanted to ask a question.

I am however not sure whether I should ask it here or on theoretical cs. I believe that this is a shared topic, so I hope it is on-topic for both sites, but where do you think is the higher chance to get a good answer? Or is it only on-topic for one of the sites?

Comment: From your description I can't see an immediate reason why you shouldn't try and ask your question here. On the other hand, the FAQ on cstheory.SE states that questions should be of "research level", so I guess yours wouldn't be very welcome there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say ask it here or on stackoverflow. cstheory is for research level questions and the questions you speak of, would be closed there.